Blender Addon: Trouble with multiple PY files with exchangeable variables
I have created several PY files that should work within a Blender addon. Variables should be defined in the INIT.py file and then used and executed in the PY files.
I followed this tip here and rebuilt my addon as in the example, but without success. When activating my addon, I get the error that a variable within one of my PY files (not the init file) has an unspecified variable. The variable should only be set when you press the custom button in the layout of my plugin.
I have googled a lot but could not find anything about my problem.

I never made a Blender addon, but having global variables in Python sounds pretty weird to me. You should probably register and instance a class and keep all global vars inside that class. How you access that class if probably a Blender thing.

After reading the documentation, I saw that addon was kind of deprecated in Blender 4.2 and now you should create Extension addon.
Blender Documentation: Create Extension
The problem is : it is really hard to find complete example.
After some trying and a lot of failures, I have come to this solution (not sure if it is the best practice...).
Some part of the code and the manifest was extracted from Blender documentation with very little modification.
Requirement:

addon_test/                  # Root folder
├── __init__.py              # Use to register your addon
├── addon_test.py            # Your addon
├── blender_manifest.toml    # Required manifest
└── db/                      # Folder containing some .py source
    ├── __init__.py          # Needed for module importation
    └── database.py          # Your source with desired values

addon_test/blender_manifest.toml
schema_version = "1.0.0"

# Example of manifest file for a Blender extension
# Change the values according to your extension
id = "move_x_axis_extension"
version = "1.0.0"
name = "Move X Axis"
tagline = "This is another extension"
maintainer = "Developer name <email@address.com>"
# Supported types: "add-on", "theme"
type = "add-on"
blender_version_min = "4.2.0"
# Put a license, it is required
license = [
  "License Real Stupidy vs Artificial Intelligence",
]
# [permissions]
# network = "Need to sync motion-capture data to server"
# files = "Import/export FBX from/to disk"
# clipboard = "Copy and paste bone transforms"

addon_test/addon_test.py
import bpy
from .db.database import *
# from .folder.filename import whatyouwant

class ObjectMoveY(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.move_y"
    bl_label = "Move Y by One"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
        
    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        for obj in scene.objects:
            obj.location.y += 1.0

        return {'FINISHED'}

# value from database.py
print(val_1)

addon_test/init.py
# Addon registration must be done here

import bpy
from .addon_test import ObjectMoveY

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ObjectMoveY.bl_idname)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ObjectMoveY)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func) 

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ObjectMoveY)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_func)

db/database.py
val_1 = 1
val_2 = 50

Build:
I use powershell but I think you can use whatever terminal you want. 
In you terminal, go to the extension folder and build your extension with Blender:
PS E:\addon_test> & 'C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.2\blender.exe' --command extension build

Installation:
Open Blender, go to: 
Edit > Preferences... > Get Extensions 
Click on the ⌄ (top right of the panel) > Install from disk 
Then select your extension.
